# Unable to run Rasa

Tags: python-3.x, rasa-nlu, rasa

I have been trying to install and use Rasa for one of my Assignment for 2 days. I have tried everything. I have tried using it with python 3.9, python 3.7.x and currently I have installed python 3.6.8 for which the error message is shown below. I have tried to find the solution via github discuss sections, but nothing has helped me yet. Can anyone tell me how can I resolve this?
Installed versions:

Rasa Version Installed: 2.3

Python version 3.6.8

Pip version 18.1

tensorflow version 2.3.1

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The install steps can be found [here](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/installation#quick-installation) along with the supported Python versions. 3.9 is not supported.

This is a TensorFlow loading issue which is probably related to your system configuration. There is more information [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/39007)

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem and solved it by [installing tensorflow using conda](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/tensorflow/).

Another way can be using virtual environment.